# Django Webpack Loader: "Assets" KeyError?

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, webpack, pip

I recently upgraded a Django app to current Django and Python versions, and updated my pip packages as well. Now I'm getting this error:

```
Django Version:  3.2.3
Exception Type:  KeyError
Exception Value: 'assets'
Exception Location: /my/env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webpack_loader/loader.py, line 90, in get_bundle
```

Looking at the Exception Location, I see:

[image]

...and looking at `assets`, confirms it has no key named `assets`:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using Django 3.0.10. Downgrading django-webpack-loader from 1.0.0 to 0.7.0 stopped the error.

Comment: I installed 0.7.0, but now I got *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpack_loader'*

Comment: I uninstalled and installed django-webpack-loader, now I don't get error, but the vue code doesn't show up.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue today so I thought I would share my solution. According to the [django-webpack-loader docs](https://github.com/django-webpack/django-webpack-loader), you need to make sure that you are using `webpack-bundle-tracker@1.0.0` on your Javascript side. You *could* downgrade to `django-webpack-loader 0.7.0`, but if your frontend bundle is large, you may be able to benefit from code splitting in the latest version. See [this issue](https://github.com/django-webpack/django-webpack-loader/issues/165).

Comment: This is the correct answer. One has to make sure the versions on both django and the node ends are compatible. Note that `webpack-bundle-tracker@1.0.0` will also create a different bundle structure (usually only a 'main' chunk group in contrast to the 'main' 'runtime' and 'vendors' groups that versions <=0.7.0 will make)

Comment: you saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, try this solution its work for me.

uninstall webpack from frontend:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-tracker
```

install webpack version:1.1.0 from frontend:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-tracker@1.1.0
```

you good to go.

if this does not work you should check https://pypi.org/project/django-webpack-loader/