# KeyError at / 'assets' and ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpack_loader'

Tags: python, django, vue.js, keyerror, django-webpack-loader

When I am at *http://127.0.0.1:8000/* I'm getting this error

> KeyError at /
>
> 'assets'

---

### In settings.py

**Installed apps**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    #own
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',    

    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',

    'crispy_forms',
    'webpack_loader',

    'users',
    'questions',
```

**Webpack Loader**

```
    WEBPACK_LOADER = {
        'DEFAULT': {
            'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'dist/',
            'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend', 'webpack-stats.json'),
        }
}
```

---

### In templates folder (index.html)

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>QuestionTime</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Vue JS</h1>

    <div id="app"></div>

    {% render_bundle 'app' %}

</body>
</html>
```

I also have the **vue.config.js** file

*(OLD see UPDATED)*

In the terminal it says this

> asset = assets['assets'][chunk]
>
> KeyError: 'assets'

Terminal (UPDATED)

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpack_loader'
```

**UPDATED:**
Uninstalled Django-webpack5-loader since it didn't do what I hoped.

But now I get another error

*See above* "Terminal (UPDATED)"

**UPDATE 2**

All errors are gone now, only issue is that, my vue doesn't show up in the browser.

Comment: Could you paste the entire error displayed in the terminal?

Comment: Do you know where `asset = assets['assets'][chunk]` is in your code? It's trying to grab a key `'assets'` and not finding it in the `assets` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be in the webpack package. This answer should help: [Django Webpack Loader: "Assets" KeyError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67808608/7838574)

Comment: I downloaded *django-webpack5-loader* but then I didn't get vue on the browser only the html, also I installed *django-webpack-loader==0.7.0*

Comment: I'm getting this error: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpack_loader'

Comment: It seems like you’ve uninstalled webpack_loader but didn’t reinstall the version that does not have the bug.

Comment: I have already done this *pip install django-webpack-loader==0.7.0*

Comment: Do you have webpack_loader in your installed apps in settings.py?

Comment: Fixed the issue, but I'm not getting my vue code in the browser now.

Comment: That is odd it sounds like the webpack isn’t being used at all

Answer (score 1):

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpack_loader'* (**SOLVED**)

If you already have done *pip install django-webpack-loader==0.7.0*

### Do like this:

First do:

> pip uninstall django-webpack-loader==0.7.0

or

> pip uninstall django-webpack-loader

After that tap **y** and then **enter**

then:

> pip install django-webpack-loader==0.7.0

Answer (score 0):

**In order to use django-webpack-loader>=1.0.0, you must ensure that webpack-bundle-tracker@1.0.0 is being used on the JavaScript side.**

https://pypi.org/project/django-webpack-loader/

This will surely work for you!