Error with pipfile when trying pipenv lock
I have errors when locking the pipfile since I have an it, this are the current dependencies
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
celery = ">=5.1.1,<5.2"
unidecode = ">=1.2.0,<1.3"
django-compressor = ">=2.4.1,<2.5"
csscompressor = ">=0.9.5,<1.0"
python3-memcached = ">=1.51,<1.52"
django-ratelimit = ">=3.0.1,<3.1"
djangorestframework = "<=3.9.0"
django-cors-headers = ">=3.7.0,<3.8"
psycopg2-binary = ">=2.8,<2.9"  # To upgrade need to address: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1293
django = "<=2.2"
django-filter = ">=2.4.0,<2.5"
docutils = ">=0.17.1,<0.18"
django-redis = ">=5.0.0,<5.1"
ipython = "<7.17"
django-hijack = ">=2.3.0,<2.4"
django-hijack-admin = ">=2.1.10,<2.2"
sentry-sdk = ">=1.1.0,<1.2"
django-webpack-loader = "<=0.7.0"  # To upgrade need to address: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67808608/django-webpack-loader-assets-keyerror
cryptography = ">=3.4.7,<3.5"
openpyxl = ">=3.0.7,<3.1"
jedi = "<0.18"  # https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12748
pillow = ">=9.2.0,<9.3"

[dev-packages]
tox = "*"
flake8 = "*"
pytest = "*"
pytest-django = "*"
coverage = "*"
django-debug-panel = "*"
django-debug-toolbar = "*"
factory-boy = "*"
pytest-cov = "*"

This is the error I've been getting

I thought it had something to do with my pip and pipenv versions, so I updated them to pip 24.2 and pipenv, version 2024.2.0, but I'm still getting the same error. Don't know where to go from here.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Please, show us text, not screenshots of text! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [Edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly format it as code block. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, shapes, sizes, positions, etc).

I figure out the problem, it seems like there are dependencies that is not compatible with my current version of pip , pipenv and python. I needed to go through each version and check it before rerunning pipenv lock.
